# AWS DynamoDB. Am I overusing my write capacity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

## Input data

DynamoDB free tier provides:

- 25 GB of Storage
- 25 Units of Read Capacity
- 25 Units of Write Capacity

Capacity units (SC/EC - strongly/eventually consistent):

- 1 RCU = 1 SC read of 4kB item/second
- 1 RCU = 2 EC reads of 4kB item/second
- 1 WCU = 1 write of 1kB item/second

My application:

- one DynamoDB table 5 RCU, 5 WCU
- one lambda

  - runs each 1 minute
  - writes 3 items ~8kB each to the DynamoDB
  - lambda execution takes <1 second

The application works ok, no throttling so far.

## CloudWatch

In my CloudWatch there are some charts (ignore the part after 7:00):

- the value on this chart is 22 WCU

[image]

- on this chart it is 110 WCU - actually figured it out - this chart resolution is 5min - 5*22=110 (leaving it here in case my future self gets confused)

[image]

## Questions

We have 3 writes of ~8kB items/second - that's ~24 WCU. That is consistent with what we see in the CloudWatch (22 WCU). But the table is configured to have only 5 WCU. I've read some other questions and as far as I understand I'm safe from paying extra if the sum of WCUs in my tables configurations is below 25.

- Am I overusing the write capacity for my table?
- Should I expect throttling or extra charges?
- As far as I can tell my usage is still within the free tier limits, but it is close (22 of 25). Am I to be charged extra if my usage gets over 25 on those charts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The configured provisioned capacity is **per second**, while the data you see in CloudWatch is **per minute**. So your configured 5 WCU per second translate to 300 WCU per minute (5 WCU * 60 seconds), which is well above the consumed 22 WCU per minute.

That should already answer your question, but to elaborate a bit on some details:

A single write of 7KB with a configured amount of 5 WCU would in theory never succeed and cause throttling, as 7KB would require 7 WCU to write, while you only have 5 WCU configured (and we can safely assume that your write would occur within one second). Fortunately the DynamoDB engineers thought about that and implemented [burst capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting). While you're not using provisioned capacity you'll save them up for up to 5 minutes to use them when you need more than the provisioned capacity. That's something to keep in mind when increasing the utilization of your capacity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation. Actually it was in the second part of your answer that resolved my confusion :)

Comment: One more thing to be completely clear. If I exceed the capacity then I get throttling - and never extra charges. Correct?

Comment: Yes till the time you manually provision capacity for your dynamo tables, which is true in your case.